# Geting user details using foreign key from res.users in Odoo

Tags: forms, model, foreign-keys, odoo, formview

I have a model `Employee` and have included a foreign key to store the user object from the `res.users` table using the following code in my model:

`user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='user id', default=lambda self: self.env.user)`

In my form, I am already capturing the user object.

Now, I want to display the user object's details (id, name, email) using the foreign key (that is the user object) in my form view.

The `<field name="user_id"/>` in my form view would display the user name of the stored object. I want to display different fields for id, email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a related field for user_id,

```
x = fields.Char(related='user_id.email')
```

like this you can access the all field values of related record.

Comment: If i add this column in my model, would it store the value in the database table?

Comment: no, if you need to store you should add store=True attribute

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Also, i tried it, but when i use it in my form view using `<field name="x"></field>` I get an error.

Comment: Field `x` does not exist

Comment: you should upgrade your addon

Comment: Yeah, I nearly forgot about that during my struggle. Thank you Burmese pythis.